# DataGrid : Half-Virtualization

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Due our requirements we are forced to disable the virtualization on the datagrid and keep every row in memory.  It works fine and it scrolls very fast.

However in order to save some memory we would like to have column virtualization enabled. So that the columns out of sight shall not be rendered and take barely any memory foot print.

is this doable? Or is WPF Datagrid's virtualization all or nothing approach?

Your help on this is highly appreciated,

Comment: Columns which are out of sight are never rendered, with or without virtualisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<DataGrid  EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="False"/>`

I think if WPF's DataGrid is providing these option then it must mean something.

Seems doable to me.

Comment: Even though the Grid seems to reacts unusually. This seems to be the answer. MS needs to improve the WPF grid badly.  Thanks